# How to Add Hue bridge in Shodan.io Search Engine

Tags: iot, hue, bridge, shodan

I am working on a special project in the Philips Hue bridge and I want to add the bridge to the search engine Shodan, I want to know how to add the IoT device in order to appear in the search engine Shodan and how to add the banner to the bridge.
For more information, you can ask questions here

Answer (score 0):

Put it on the Internet and either wait a bit (~1 week) for Shodan to pick it up organically or request an immediate scan of it using the Shodan API/ command-line interface:

https://help.shodan.io/the-basics/on-demand-scanning

Alternatively, you can also reach out to support@shodan.io and they can help you get it indexed.